# Issue with Magento Order-number

Tags: orders, sales-order, magento2.2.3

We built a website with Magento 2.2 community version. We have got a strange issue with the Order number in Magento.

For example, Magento was at number 100034467 and the next order number that came in was 100034470. The order numbers 100034468, 100034469 were missing. Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

We have no idea what happened to the missing order numbers. Is this a normal one in Magento?

If this really an issue, please let me know your thoughts to resolve this.

Now is the peak season for us, we would like to resolve this issue as soon as possible.

Looking forward to your help and support.

Comment: Are you using paypal button in your cart and product details page?

Comment: No, I'm not using the PayPal button in the cart and product details page.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, Do you have any updates for me?

Comment: Not sure as I had that issue with paypal, when I disabled it my problem gets resolved.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, Glad to know that you have solved your problem. Note: I'm using DIBS payment for our site. If you have any idea, please share with me. Thanks.